# C header file is causing warning "ISO C requires a translation unit to contain at least one declaration"

Tags: c, qt-creator, compiler-warnings

Using Qt Creator I made these plain C files just to test my understanding:

`main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "linked.h"

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    printf("%d", linked());
    return 0;
}
```

`linked.h`

```
#ifndef LINKED_H_
#define LINKED_H_

int linked(void);

#endif // LINKED_H
```

`linked.c`

```
int linked()
{
    return 5;
}
```

The IDE shows a warning on the line of `linked.h` in-between `#define LINKED_H_` and `int linked(void);` which reads

```
ISO C requires a translation unit to contain at least one declaration
```

My best guess about what this means is that any header or other C file, if it is in a project, should get used in the main file at least once somewhere.  I've tried searching the warning but if this has been answered elsewhere, I'm not able to understand the answer.  It seems to me I've used the `linked` function and so it shouldn't give me this warning.  Can anyone explain what's going on?

The program compiles and runs exactly as expected.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the program. It's a bug in your IDE. The rule is basically "The empty file is not a valid C file." But your file isn't empty.

Comment: Everything is fine, your IDE is confused.

Comment: In the list of source files to compile, is linked.h one of the files? If so, that would tell the IDE to compile it by itself, which would cause the message, and the remedy would be to remove it from that list.

Comment: The `int linked()` definition doesn't match the declaration, which takes no arguments.

Comment: @jamesdlin: Those are compatible declarations, per C 2018 6.7.6.3 15: “… If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function definition that contains a (possibly empty) identifier list, both shall agree in the number of parameters, and the type of each prototype parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the application of the default argument promotions to the type of the corresponding identifier.…”

Comment: @EricPostpischil Can that happen if `linked.c` doesn't `#include` `linked.h`?

Comment: Re “My best guess about what this means is that any header or other C file, if it is in a project, should get used in the main file at least once somewhere”: There is no need to guess; the message means what it says. Each translation unit must contain one declaration. (Actually, it must contain at least one *external-declaration*.) A translation unit is essentially the source file being compiled plus everything it includes. (For the curious, this arises from the grammar in C 2018 6.9 1.)

Comment: @jamesdlin: Yes, the two types are compatible, so they satisfy the rules for function calls in 6.5.2.2. Essentially, the compiler does not need to see the definition—the C standard’s rules for compatibility guarantee that the code for the call created by the compiler when it can see the declaration will work for the code created by the compiler when it can see the definition. Even though the declarations are different, the compatibility rules mean that code to call one will work to call the other. It is not good practice, of course, but it is not out of conformance with the standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The need for guessing is that I don't know what it says exactly ... because I'm just now learning C.

Comment: @EricPostpischil About whether `linked.h` is set to compile, I believe I need to look that up in the make file.  The one Qt-Creator defaults to is huge, but to the best of my understanding, `linked.h` is not among the files to compile.   The `linked.o:` line is followed by the path to `linked.c`.  The `main.o:` line makes reference to the `main.c` and `linked.h` files, but on the next like it contains `$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o main.o ../test/main.c`.  I assume this is fine and does not represents a command to compile `linked.h`.

Comment: Getting the same error on https://github.com/redcode/Mines/blob/master/sources/prefix.pch which has no method signatures

Comment: Is it possible you have an irregular whitespace or non-rendered character on that line? You could try deleting that file and rewriting it from scratch

Comment: @Addem Can you check to see if my answer works?

Comment: @JL2210 This came up so long ago I don't have the application any more and don't even remember how to use Qt Creator.  I didn't get very far with it and work took my attention away after I stalled on it.  Right now I don't have the time to figure it out again.

Comment: @BenLeggiero Since you're the bounty holder, does my solution work for you?

Comment: @JL2210 Dude seems MIA so remind me in about 24 hours.  If Ben still hasn't responded I'll just accept your answer, hope that gives you the bounty.

Comment: Note that the `linked.c` file _should_ include the `linked.h` header so the compiler can make sure the definition of the function matches the declaration in the header.  Without that `#include`, you run the risk of a mismatch.  Personally, I'd ensure that the declaration in the source and the header match, so `linked.c` would contain `int linked(void) { … }` with the explicit `void` instead of empty parentheses to match the correct declaration in the header.

Comment: I think you need to show the exact compiler command line you are using when you get the error.  It might be helpful to identify which version of GCC you're using.  I've seen similar error messages in the past under various circumstances, but I've not immediately been able to reproduce it on macOS Mojave 10.14.6 with GCC 9.2.0 (home-built) and Xcode 11.2.1 (which surprised me — I thought I knew how to get the error).  The nearest I've got is `ISO C forbids an empty translation unit [-Werror=pedantic]` — which doesn't exactly match your error message or the context shown in the question.

Comment: @JL2210 That solution did not work for me, but it seems to help the largest number of people. I'll give it the bounty and keep searching for the cause of the problem I'm facing. Thanks for asking!

Comment: @Addem sorry; I don't check Stack on the weekends (after 17:00 my time Friday, before 08:00 my time Monday). Glad it helped find a useful answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the issue is that you don't `#include "linked.h"` from `linked.c`. The current `linked.c` file doesn't have any declarations; it only has one function definition.

To fix this, add this line to `linked.c`:

```
#include "linked.h"
```

I don't know why it says this is an issue with `linked.h`, but it seems to be quite a coincidence that the line number you pointed out just happens to be the line number of the end of `linked.c`.

Of course, that may be all this is; a coincidence. So, if that doesn't work, try putting some sort of external declaration in this file. The easiest way to do that is to include a standard header, such as `stdio.h`. I would still advise you to `#include "linked.h"` from inside `linked.c`, though.

Comment: In C unlike C++ there is no function mangling. The linker is able to match the function call, no prototype is required, no include is required. Although if the return type isn't int I'd expect undefined behaviour. Nevertheless it will compile. Try it yourself with a simple example - no includes. Try something like gcc main.c test.c -o test. Call a function in test from main with no include.

Comment: @MikeSeeds I have little to no experience in C++, so I wouldn't know. My main concern was that `int linked() {` is not a declaration, but a definition. I think the OP may have made an accidental error when looking at the file name -- I do it all the time.

Answer (score -1):

add a header

```
#ifndef LINKED_H_
#define LINKED_H_

#include <stdio.h>

int linked(void);

#endif // LINKED_H
```

Answer (score -3):

The way you wrote the code, you need to use:

```
extern int linked(void);
```

(notice the additional "extern"). That might help with the issue.

---

Also, the code in **linked.c** should be:

```
int linked(void)
{
    return 5;
}
```

(Notice the "parameter" - "void").

Comment: `extern` is implied in global declarations.

Answer (score -4):

According to [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/error-iso-c-forbids-empty-source-file), you need some declaration in the header file, but you do have one. Perhaps `LINKED_H_` is defined elsewhere, or the compiler is seeing that it's possible that the precompiler condition might result in an empty parse.

Perhaps this header file will work for you:

**linked.h**

```
#ifndef LINKED_H_
#define LINKED_H_

int linked(void);

#endif // LINKED_H

char __allowLinkedHToBeIsoCCompliant = 1;
```

Comment: It's not compliant if you use that double-underscore. And that will cause that symbol to be present in every file `linked.h` is included in, which will most likely cause a "multiple definition" error.

Comment: Didn't know about that double-underscore caveat; thanks! Hmmm possibly might cause that error, but when I was testing it locally I didn't run into that. Though I think I'm on the right track. Any suggestions?

Comment: Again, this would only be an issue, if one would try to compile `linked.h` standalone as a compilation unit, not when it is included somewhere else.

Comment: @BenLeggiero I can't reproduce JL2210's solution but there's a bounty for solving the problem.  If you try his solution and it works, let me know and I'll accept his answer.

Comment: @Ctx Interesting. I was having this error with [a prefix header in another project entirely](https://github.com/redcode/Mines/blob/master/sources/prefix.pch), which is implicitly included everywhere, so including it wouldn't be the fix.